# Binding UserControl to ViewModel (Caliburn Micro WPF)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls, caliburn.micro

I am creating a login form that will be used by many different applications. The login will always have the same logic, so I'd like to bind a viewmodel and do all logic there (Retrieving login info from database, etc). I created a new `UserControl`, `MainView` and a ViewModel, `MainViewModel` both of which are in a `Login` namespace.

The form continues to run everything in the code-behind, but nothing in the VM. 
Is there another way of binding that I am not aware of?

**Code-Behind `MainView.Xaml.vb`**

```
Imports Caliburn.Micro

Namespace Login
   Public Class MainView

      Public Sub New()
        MsgBox("TEST code-behind")
      End Sub

   End Class
End Namespace
```

**VM `MainViewModel.vb`**

```
Imports Caliburn.Micro

Namespace Login
    Public Class MainViewModel
        Inherits PropertyChangedBase

        Public Sub New()
            MsgBox("TEST ViewModel")
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

**Xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Login.MainView"
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:cLogin.Login"
         cal:Bind.Model="cLogin.Login.MainViewModel" (not sure if needed due to naming)
         ... >
```

**EDIT**
This is how I have added the `UserControl` as a separate window before the user is logged in, I can see the content, but none of the properties inside the ViewModel bind

```
Dim login As New Window
    With login
        .WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None
        .ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize
        .SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight
        .Content = New MainView()
    End With

login.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Do you see the MainView on the screen when you start the app? What's your shell view?

Comment: I edited the post to show you how i plan on implementing this usercontrol @mm8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating the window explicitly, you also need to explicitly set its `DataContext`:

```
Dim login As New Window
    With login
        .WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None
        .ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize
        .SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight
        .Content = New MainView()
        .DataContext = New MainViewModel()
End With
```

You should also bind the attached `Bind.Model` property to the `DataContext` in the view:

```
cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}"
```